# Recording Controller in Jmeter not recording in a localhost web server

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, jmeter, localhost

I'm currently testing my application using phpmyadmin as my local web server.

Here's the steps I've taken so far:

1. In the Test Plan, I added a Thread Group, an HTTP Request Defaults and Recording Controller.
2. In the Workbench, I added a HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder, and a View Results Tree.

I already removed the contents in the **No proxy for field** in my browser, after removing that, the **View Results Tree** is working and is recording the pages I've navigate in my application.

My problems and questions are:

1. The Recording Controller is not recording the pages I navigated.
2. What did I do wrong?
3. **Is Recording Controller not applicable for localhost web server testing?**

I hope that someone may help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Hi yes. I'm sorry for this late feedback. I reviewed the steps I've taken, and that my mistake was that I did not include a **.*\.php** as URL to Include in the  HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. I remembered lately that all my files in my localhost was my .php files, and that solved my problem.

Comment: Its done. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your browser configuration that localhost is not excluded from proxy managed urls.

Also be aware that you shoud use the Recording Template.

In Menu, select File > Templates  > Recording.

See:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/templates-or-how-to-speed-up-your-tests-scripting-with-jmeter/

Comment: Thank you, I double checked it and my mistake was in the **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** itself.

Comment: Good, I updated my answer anyway, it might be interesting for you

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Also please check if you are using correct path for recording in HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder ->Recording controller, also port number should same on HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder and browser proxy.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!